# handleSubmit in formik does not get triggered

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I´m trying to submit my Formik form and get the values of my fields but I don get to trigger the function I´m passing trough onSubmit attribute of Formik tag.

When I click the button submit it validate perfectly everything but does not trigger that function i want to reach the debugger that is inside of "handleSubmitContactModal".

can someone help me please?

My formik is inside a bootstrap modal, maybe it does not work because of that?

```
export const ContactModal = () =>{
    
    const initialContactFormValues = {
        NameSurname: "",
        Phone: "",
        Email: "",
        Comment: "",
        LegalConsent: false
    }

    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        NameSurname: Yup.string()
            .min(2, "* El nombre es demasiado corto")
            .max(100, "* El nombre es demasiado largo")
            .required("* Este campo es obligatorio"),
        Phone: Yup.string()
            .matches(/^(?:6[0-9]|7[1-9])[0-9]{7}$/, "* Introduce un teléfono válido")
            .required("* Este campo es obligatorio"),
        Email: Yup.string()
            .email("* Introduce un email válido.")
            .required("* Este campo es obligatorio"),
        Comment: Yup.string()
            .min(2, "* El comentario es demasiado corto")
            .max(1000, "* El comentario es demasiado largo")
            .required("* Este campo es obligatorio"),
        LegalConsent: Yup.bool().oneOf([true], "* Debe aceptar los términos")
    });

    const handleSubmitContactModal = (values, helpers) =>{
        debugger;
        // event.preventDefault();

        // const contactForm = event.target.form;

        // let contactFormValues = {
        //     Name: contactForm[0].value.trim(),
        //     Phone: contactForm[1].value.trim(),
        //     Email: contactForm[2].value.trim(),
        //     Comment: contactForm[3].value.trim(),
        //     LegalConsent: contactForm[4].checked
        // }

        // console.log(contactFormValues)

        // Fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PALDENTAL_BACK_URL}/contacto`,
        // {
        //     method : "post", 
        //     data : {...contactFormValues}
        // })
        // .then(data =>{
        //     console.log(data)
        // })
        // .catch(error =>{
        //     console.log(error)
        // })

    }

    return(
        <div className="modal fade" id="ContactModal" tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="ContactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header justify-content-end">
                        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <Formik 
                        initialValues={initialContactFormValues} 
                        validationSchema={validationSchema} 
                        onSubmit={handleSubmitContactModal}>
                        {({ values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur }) => {
                            // console.log(values, errors, touched)
                            return(
                                <Form id="contactForm">
                                    <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-start align-items-center mt-n4">
                                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="ContactModalLabel">Contacto</h5>
                                        <h3>Introduce tus datos</h3>
                                        
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="NameSurname">
                                                Nombre y apellidos <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <Field id="NameSurnameInput" name="NameSurname" className="form-group__input"/>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="NameSurname" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Phone">
                                                Teléfono <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="input-group flex-nowrap">
                                                <Field id="phoneInput" name="Phone" className="form-group__input"/>
                                                <i className="input-group-text icon icon-info" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" title="El teléfono no puede contener espacios, tampoco es necesario el prefijo" data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip"></i>
                                            </div>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="Phone" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Email">
                                                Email <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <Field id="emailInput" name="Email" className="form-group__input"/>
                                            <ErrorMessage name="Email" className="form-group__error" component="span"/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label className="form-group__label" htmlFor="Comment">
                                                Comentario <span className="mandatory">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            <div className="comment">
                                                <textarea 
                                                    id="commentInput" 
                                                    name="Comment"
                                                    type="text" 
                                                    className="form-group__input" 
                                                    rows="5"
                                                    value={values.Comment} 
                                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                                    onBlur={handleBlur}>
                                                </textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            { errors.Comment && touched.Comment &&
                                                <span className="form-group__error">
                                                    * {errors.Comment}
                                                </span>
                                            }
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="form-group__legal px-3">
                                            <input 
                                                id="legalConsentInput" 
                                                name="LegalConsent" 
                                                type="checkbox" 
                                                onChange={handleChange} 
                                                data-bs-toggle="tooltip" 
                                                data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                                                title={`${ errors.LegalConsent && touched.LegalConsent ? errors.LegalConsent : ""}`} data-bs-custom-class="custom-tooltip" />

                                            <p>He leido y acepto las condiciones de <Link to="/terminos-legales" target="_blank">Aviso Legal</Link> y <Link to="/terminos-legales" target="_blank">Política de privacidad</Link></p>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                                        <button type="submit" className="btn-pd-primary">Enviar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            )
                        }}
                    </Formik>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please try to only include the minimum code required to repro your problem, this way will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: SOLUTION: I didn´t link "LegalConsent" error from validationSchema of yup with anything so that´s way handleSubmit never got triggered. In addition if you have at least one error the handleSubmit function does not get triggered neither. So by this form you avoid the extra validation inside handleSubmit related to check if key are empty ;D